# header nocache not working as expected

Tags: php, header, browser-cache

The header on my site script includes the following:

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

These lines are called prior to any output/whitespace.

This is what is showing in my live header viewer:

```
POST /includes/whosonline.php HTTP/1.1
Host: mysite.org
User-Agent: Linux/Firefox 11
Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-Prototype-Version: 1.6.0.2
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: https://mysite.org?id=123
Content-Length: 0
Cookie: [cookie stuff removed]
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Note that the headers of the script specify that the browser not cache the page.  The Expires date is before the current date.

Why is this not working?

Comment: Content-Length:0 ? Empty page?

Comment: try to append `, max-age=0"` in the first Cache-Control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested here with firefox and chrome (just in case) and it seems to be working!

- OS: Mac OS X Lion
- Server: Nginx 1.2
- PHP: 5.3

http://cl.ly/041H1h1s1Q1P433W1m3Q

http://cl.ly/0o2B2I1a2N1I0N101E2w

My guesses: maybe your http server or php version has some kind of bug. So maybe, you should try to update both or test with another http server.